# How to flip an SVG horizontally using TweenMax (Greensock)?

Tags: javascript, svg, css-transforms, gsap

I am trying to do some animation using Greensock and the rest are okay, except that I'm not sure how to flip the SVG the way I'd like to.

I did the code like so:

```
.to($tri_yellowgreen, 0.25, {rotationY:180, transformOrigin:"left top"})
```

..but the arrow moves to the bottom and not flip on the same position.

CODEPEN DEMO:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJOBma

I'd like to go from this:

[image]

...to this (the yellow-green arrow flipped):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution could be replacing this:

```
.to($tri_yellowgreen, 0.25, {rotationY:180, transformOrigin:"left top"})
```

with that:

```
.fromTo($tri_yellowgreen, 0.25, {transformOrigin:'right top'}, {rotationY: 180})
```

Basically the `transformOrigin` has to be applied before the tween even begins, hence the usage of **[`.fromTo()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/fromTo/)** method instead of a `.to()` call.